# Package Management - Is This Possible?

Tags: frontend, package-managers

Wondered if anyone could shed some light on whether this is a possibility and how we could go about integrating it if it is.

Basically, we want to start sharing our front-end code with external agencies and this code is split up in to different "modules". For example, two of our modules might look like this:

**Form Module**

- Form.scss
- List item
- Requires Typography
- Requires Branding
- Requires Grid

### **Map Module**

- map.scss
- Requires Grid only

So you can see if an agency wanted our map module, then they'd only need our grid and map.scss where as if they wanted forms, they need a lot more. We don't want to give the agency everything if they don't need it.

I thought something like Bower could work as we have each "module" in a separate git repo, so the grid is in a separate repo to the forms etc.

Then the agency could do like `bower install forms` and they'd get the forms as well as the typography, grid and branding all neatly put in to the correct folder strucutre. However, this isn't possible with Bower in that it splits each git repo in to its own folder.

Is there anything out there that would allow this approach or is it a case of that we would have to put the typography files in each repo that needed it and then every time we wanted to updated the typography, update it in multiple locations?

Hope that made sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating my own NPM package to do this. If anyone is interested it is called MacGet :)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/macget